# Why did someone change the wording of my question?

Tags: discussion

I posted [a question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/137668/revisions) and someone (Scott Seidman?) totally re-worded it. Why?

Comment: Point us at the original question. Scott is known to reword questions for clarity.

Comment: Someone else may change the title for your question if you don’t...

Comment: Is that the one migrated to home improvement?

Comment: @Cpaul. What was the original question? Why and who deleted it? Was it migrated?

Comment: The original question title was confusing. It said "can light wiring totally messed up?" Because "can" is a verb as well as a noun, the original message sounded like some kind of very poorly worded question. (It made me think of the "I can has cheezburger" meme). Scott maybe went a little too far in changing the question subject heading. But I don't think he changed the essence of the question.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but all edits are peer reviewed if not approved by the original author, which means that at least 2 people thought it was an improvement

Comment: If you do revert, please at least fix the main subject line. For example "Is the wiring of this can light fixture totally messed up?"

Comment: @loudnoises [They are only peer reviewed until you reach 2000 reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). After that, all edits go through instantly. - I wish some of my edits were peer reviewed, but I can't force peer reviewing. - Scott Seidman has more than 2k rep.

Comment: By the way, this question will certainly be closed because it is totally off-topic. But I felt like the OP deserved an answer. If I am not mistaken, it would be OK to ask this question in meta.

Comment: I also read the original question "can light wiring totally messed up?" to find out what a can light is or see if the question was written in pigeon English. I was no wiser when I finished. It needed to be fixed.

Comment: I've voted to close this. It seems like the original edit history is no longer preserved after the move, so it's not possible to answer anything specific. The generic question "Why is a question edited" is way too broad.

Comment: - and the question has been further edited by high-rep users over at DIY - so seems to me like SE working as intended.

Comment: @pipe there is no edit prior to the move. And the history would be preserved even if it it had been. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/369695/revisions

Comment: @Passerby Then I don't understand this question. Scott has not edited anything, and it was never even edited here on EE.

Comment: Because the migration system on stack exchange is transparent enough that it takes a while for people to realize what happened. People not used to the system will obviously come back to the website they first used, the one their account is on.  They don't now that diy isn't ee. It's all the same network.

Answer (score 6):

It was edited to improve its readability and usability for others asking the same question. It is clearer what the question is about with the new title than "is my wiring correct". This doesn't change what you are asking, it's meaning, just how it's written.

It's normal for these edits to happen here, by design, and encouraged greatly.

As it stands, the question was migrated to DIY the home improvement stack exchange because it's mostly off topic here.